# Flutter - How to adjust the alignment of VideoProgressIndicator()

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a video at the center and the VideoProgressIndicator was set to

```
 Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: VideoProgressIndicator(
            _vidController,
            this.allowScrubbing;,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
          ),
        ),
```

The output is at the bottom of the screen. My goal is to have it under the video. Attached an image: The black part is the video and the red part at the bottom is the VideoProgressIndicator.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsDFL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can put you videoPlayer and progress in column like

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text("Your PLayer"),
         VideoProgressIndicator(
        _vidController,
        this.allowScrubbing;,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      ),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: Hi. I tried it but the VideoProgressIndicator is displayed at the center of the vid. It looks the same when I put Alignment.center instead of Alignment.bottomCenter

Comment: set Height of VideoProgressIndicator or put it in sizeBox

Comment: Hi. My goal is to move the VPI in below the video that is centered. I used positioned but it only works well in the emulator that I'm using but in other emulators the VPI is at the center. How should I do this?

Comment: is your videoView fit to screen?